# Adding links with active classes

Tags: class, magento, navigation, php

I use the method described bellow to add links with active classes for my CMS pages. The problem is that when I click on any of the links it becomes active, but the class remains even after clicking some of the other links. So the rest of the links don't obtain an active class but just the first opened. Any idea where the problem lies?

```
    <li class="level0 nav-2 parent <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'custom') != false ) :?> active<?php endif;?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') . 'custom' ?>"><?php echo $this->__('TEXT OF MY LINK 1')  ?></a>
    </li>

    <li class="level0 nav-3 parent <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'wholesale') != false ) :?> active<?php endif;?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') . 'wholesale' ?>"><?php echo $this->__('TEXT OF MY LINK 2')  ?></a>
    </li>

    <li class="level0 nav-4 parent <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'faq') != false ) :?> active<?php endif;?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') . 'faq' ?>"><?php echo $this->__('TEXT OF MY LINK 3')  ?></a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'custom') != false )
```

to

```
if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'custom') !== false )
```

or you can get current CMS page identifier and check accordingly, like

```
$current_page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
//and check & add class
<li class="level0 nav-2 parent <?php if($current_page == 'custom' ):?> active <?php endif;?>">
....
```

Comment: Strange but it doesn't work. No changes - the class appears with the first click and remains for the same link.

Comment: @capola do you get proper name in $current_page variable ..?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of checking `!=false` you can directly use below code.

```
<?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'custom')) :?> active<?php endif;?>
```

After updating this, clear all cache from Magento Admin from System->Cache Management

OR
Updated code:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'custom') :?> active<?php endif;?>
```

Try this, Hope will help!

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work too. The code is in template\codnitive\sidenav\navigation.phtml - the Codnitives navigation extension, if you think it matters.

Comment: Use `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();` in stead of `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),'custom')`. Also I have updated code.

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't help. Only the first link gets an active class.